# How can I run gcp without an X server?

Tags: server, xorg, command-line, dbus

I installed `gcp` because I often copy large directories from one place to another and I want to see a progress bar to know how long it will take, but this is running on a minimal server so I don't have X and running `gcp` gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gcp", line 678, in <module>
    gcp = GCP()
  File "/usr/bin/gcp", line 205, in __init__
    raise e
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

Is there anything I can do about it without installing X? Are there any alternatives to gcp that work from the console and support recursive copying with progress bar?

Answer (score 7):

To run `gcp` or any program requiring dbus from a text session, you can use the command `dbus-launch`, as in the following example:

```
dbus-launch gcp -r dir1 dir2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this Advanced Copy Command: https://github.com/jarun/advcpmv

It is based on the default cp binary and adds an additional parameter that shows a progess bar. You compile it, place it someplace on your system and add the directory where it is at the front of the PATH environment variable, so it is used instead of the default cp command. Usage is then the same as before, just with the additional parameter.